# How to load only summary of post without loading full page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogs

On my blog, on home page I am showing summary of posts instead of full posts. I was thinking it was loading only summary which contains a image and some lines from the post, but when I tested it on a Speed-Testing website, I saw that it is loading full page, every image and then hiding the images on other content . It is affecting my page load speed. Is there any way so only the summary will load.

```
 </script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var thumbnail_mode = &quot;no-float&quot; ; 
  summary_noimg = 430; 
  summary_img = 500; 
  img_thumb_height = 100; 
  img_thumb_width = 120; 
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[ 
  function removeHtmlTag(strx,chop){ 
    if(strx.indexOf("<")!=-1) 
    { 
      var s = strx.split("<"); 
      for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){ 
        if(s[i].indexOf(">")!=-1){ 
          s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">")+1,s[i].length); 
        } 
      } 
      strx = s.join(""); 
    } 
    chop = (chop < strx.length-1) ? chop : strx.length-2; 
    while(strx.charAt(chop-1)!=' ' && strx.indexOf(' ',chop)!=-1) chop++; 
    strx = strx.substring(0,chop-1); 
    return strx+'...'; 
  } 
  function createSummaryAndThumb(pID){ 
    var div = document.getElementById(pID); 
    var imgtag = ""; 
    var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img"); 
    var summ = summary_noimg; 
    if(img.length>=1) { 
      imgtag = '<span style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></span>'; 
      summ = summary_img; 
    } 
    var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>'; 
    div.innerHTML = summary; 
  } 
  //]]></script>
```

This is the code which I have used to make summary.

Comment: This question is too broad as to give you any assistance. What CMS are you using?

Comment: Most likely you won't be able to do anything about this. It depends on your CMS. If the CMS has a method for getting a "summary" (which may be a different column in the database), then you may be able to do it. Most likely, the posts are all loaded via HTTP (as opposed to AJAX), so you definitely can't do anything with JS.

Comment: You need to provide your code and what you have tried to fix it. Only then you can expect more help from the community

Comment: @Reddy I have added the code.

Comment: @AlainNisam I think blogger have a feature called 'JUMP BREAK'. When we add a jump break in our post, a read more button is placed. After placing the jump break the further content is hided and a Read More button appears(On home page). I haven't tried it  yet. Do you any idea?? Can this work???

Comment: Yes, it looks like that would work for sure. Try it and send me the blog URL so we can see if it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jump-link is the right method for this problem. I just added a jump-break and it worked exactly as I was expecting. I also customized the read more button to make it cool.